# How to convert a blade file to HTML and save it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

For example, there is a file `\resources\views\test.blade.php`：

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
   <div class="container">
      {{ $article->content }}
   </div>
@endsection
```

I want to save it as `\resources\views\html\test.html`. What should I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would try something like this, although I haven't test it my self:

```
File::put('test.html',
    view('resources.views.test')
        ->with(["article" => $article])
        ->render()
);
```

Comment: @aaron0207 Yes, both are wrappers for php's `file_put_content()`

Comment: @aaron0207 If this answered your question, please consider accepting it

Comment: It isn't my question, I just tested the code and upvoted because it worked